# Firebase function: check if multiple keys exist

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is there a short/efficient way to check if multiple keys exist (even better if I can read several keys in a single call)?
The only way I manage to achieve a similar result is by checking if `key1` exists, `.then` check if `key2` exists etc. Make it very ugly if I have 5 keys to check.
The keys are in completely different locations, so I don't want to just get the common ancestor and read the snap, as it's too much data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check all the keys without using then(), but collect all the promises into an array (I'll call it `promises`), then use `Promise.all(promises)` to get another promise that's resolved after all the others resolve.  They can now potentially execute in parallel without having to wait for each other.

Comment: Can you please post a piece of code to demonstrate this?

Comment: There's lots of samples in the official sample code.  Here's one.  https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/message-translation/functions/index.js